# Max extension of spring mass system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy-conservation, spring

While attempting problems of simple harmonic motion I came across this problem, which has gotten me confused.

A fixed horizontal spring is stretched by a constant  force $F$. I am required to obtain the maximum elongation of that spring. But the problem is which method is correct, the energy method or the force method? Do let me know the misconception in the wrong path.

## Method 1:

$$\text{For Equilibrium}\\ \; F= kx_\text{max}\\ \implies x_\text{max}= \frac{F}{k}\;.$$

## Method 2:

$$\text{Work done by the force}\; = \text{change in potential energy of the spring}\\ \text{i.e.} \; F\cdot x_\text{max}= \frac{1}{2} kx_\text{max}^2\\ \implies x_\text{max} = \frac{2F}{k}\; .$$

Comment: When it specifically asked for maximum elongation it is good to use energy conservation method.

Comment: @SathyaramGanapathy I believe the OP is asking why he obtained different results using different methods

Comment: @brucesmitherson But his question doesn't ask that--"But the problem is which method should I take,the energy method or the force method..."

Comment: @SathyaramGanapathy I know, but I guess that based on the picture, still I might be wrong

Comment: I meant to ask that.Apologies for misinterpretations

Comment: You can edit your question to clarify that for future readers.

Comment: In my opinion, the energy forumla just gives the potential energy stored in the string. In your method 2, you haven't accounted for the energy lost due to heat. I would prefer to use method 1 in these situations where I am not sure about all the energy changes.

Comment: But I have considered only the ideal case

Comment: Even in ideal cases, there is a chance of losing energy as heat. The same happens in case of RC circuits, half the energy is lost as heat & the other half is stored in the capacitor.

Comment: @YashasSamaga your comment is unrelated to the question and might confuse the OP

Comment: Basically, which answer is the correct one depends on how you interpret the question. If it is held a rest by the constant force, the force method is correct, if you have a constant force along the path and the system oscillates, the energy method is the correct one

Comment: Your main problem was to consider $F$ as constant. Restoring force is increasing as you displace the spring away from the equilibrium.

Comment: The statement of the question is ambiguous.  Is it being *held* by a constant force, or is it being *actively stretched* by a constant force.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first method is giving the correct answer. In writing the work done by the force, you are assuming that the force $F$ itself is constant throughout the extension. However, this is not true. While extending the spring in a quasi-static way, the force $F$ must always match exactly the spring force at that time. This is needed so that at the end of the extension, the spring remains at rest. Once we understand this, we note that the force at extension $x$ is $F(x) = k x$. Then, the work done along the path is
$$
\int_0^{x_{\max}} F(x) dx = \frac{1}{2} k x_\max^2
$$
The latter of course is precisely the potential energy of the spring. Thus, the "energy conservation" equation is trivial and does not yield any new information.

Comment: But it is stated that a constant force is applied.

Comment: if you assume a constant force the spring would still reach a maximum extent at zero speed, what is it wrong with that?

Comment: What you say does make sense.I suppose the author might have missed out on that

Comment: It is stated that a constant force is used to hold the spring in place. It is not stated whether a constant force was used to bring the spring into its current state. You made the latter assumption.

Comment: In truth, I have also made an assumption about the type of force that was used to bring the spring into its current state. However, it can be shown that no matter what types of forces you use to bring the spring into its current state, the work done by force will equal exactly the energy of the spring, so the energy conservation equation is always trivial.

Comment: @brucesmitherson A constant force $F$ will not ever cause the spring to be at rest. Rather, it will always be oscillating.

Comment: I am not saying that is incorrect, I am saying that it will still reach a maximum extension at zero speed. So the mistake is to assume zero acceleration at the end. Th first method is wrong

Comment: Can you kindly demonstrate that. I am having trouble understanding it

Comment: @brucesmitherson - Yes, that's right. However, the way the question is phrased, I understand it as being held fixed with a constant force $F$, i.e. $v=0,a=0$.

Comment: @Prahar I read the question again and I agree with you it can be interpreted both ways

Answer (score 4):

If you use a constant force along the path, the spring will move past the position where $F=kx$, because it will reach that point at some speed. Thus it is incorrect to use the force method in the way you used it, because at maximal extension $v=0$ but $a\neq0$. The energy method as you used it will give the correct answer.  If, instead, the force is used to keep the spring elongated at rest, then the force method is correct. To see why  read Prahar's answer.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. +1.